# using ajax GET method with php

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax GET call to the server 
when I give the specific URL localhost/try1.php?action=test
it's working correctly, but when i omit ?action=test it's not working correctly 
here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#myEvent').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/try1.php",
          data: {action: 'test'},
          success: function(responseJson){
            alert("hello world");
          },
          error: function(result){
            alert("error");
          } 
    });
});
});
 </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="#" id="myEvent">clickme</a>
   <?php
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        echo $action; 
        switch($action) {
        case 'test' :

            echo $action; 
            break;

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: do you want to send ajax request in same page?

Comment: yes, I want to get the response at the same page

Comment: Are you _sending_ this request to the same URL as the one the page was loaded from? If so – _why_? It makes little sense to answer the AJAX request with a complete HTML document again. Use a second script with a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  try1.php instead of /try1.php.

g